Spinorial representation of Weyl group of SO(8)
First of all, physicist here, doing my best to post this question as rigorously as possible.
My question is: how can I construct a spinorial representation of the Weyl group of $SO(8)$?
Attempt at a solution:
By using the eight $16$-dimensional $\Gamma$ matrices of a $C\ell_8$ Clifford algebra, I can construct a $16$-dimensional spinorial representation of the $28$ generators of the $SO(8)$ through $B_{ij}=[\Gamma_i,\Gamma_j]$.
Using this set of matrices, I combined them into a Chevalley basis for the generators of $SO(8)$, which I denote as $H_i$ ($i=1,\ldots,4$) plus $24$ other generators $E_{\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ are the $24$ different roots ($4$ of which are simple).
I now wish to construct a representation of the corresponding Weyl group $W(SO(8))$, whose $24$ elements correspond to the reflection about the hyperplane perpendicular to each $\alpha$.
I feel that each generator of $W(SO(8))$ in this representation should be related to $E_{\alpha}$ but I can't figure out how. I've tried literature suggested in some related questions here (like R.W. Carter, Finite Groups of Lie Type: Conjugacy Classes and Complex Characters) but I've had no luck so far.
Thank you very much for any help!

Note the Weyl group is not a subgroup of the original Lie group. It can instead be realised as a subquotient, i.e. it is a quotient of a subgroup. So there is no reason for it to have a natural representation on the same vector space as the original group unless the thing we quotient out by acts trivially but this is not the case.
Indeed, compare with the fact that $\operatorname{SO}(8)$ doesn't act on the spinor representations while $\operatorname{Spin}(8)$ does and the former is also a quotient of the latter (the "vector representation" is fine since we are quotienting out by the kernel of that representation).
In the case of the Weyl group it is given by $W = N(T)/T$ where $T \leq \operatorname{Spin}(8)$ is a maximal torus and $N(T)$ is its normaliser. But since $T$ doesn't act trivially on any representation of $\operatorname{Spin}(8)$ except trivial ones we cannot define a useful action this way. Note this would be true of any semisimple Lie group.

Thank you very much for your answer! This will take me some time to digest but just so I'm 100% clarified, does this mean that I cannot find a representation of $W(SO(8))$ that is 16-dimensional? I kind of understand your reasoning for not existing spinorial representations but I would be satisfied with 24 generators in the form of 16x16 matrices at this point.

@user38680 Finding a $16$-dimensional representation is easy. There is always the trivial one, of course, but others can be found without difficulty. They just won't have anything to do with the representation of $\operatorname{Spin}(8)$. Also what do you mean by $24$ "generators" here? The Weyl group can be generated by only $4$ elements (and I believe it has $192$ elements total not $24$ as well). Note it is a finite group not a Lie group so it doesn't have a Lie algebra so the idea of generators is different here.

I see, my understanding of Weyl groups is very limited indeed, I thought they were Lie groups as well. If I may have one last question: what does a decomposition at the Weyl group level mean?

@user38680 I would interpret that to mean decomposing the Weyl group into a product of two smaller groups. For example if your semisimple Lie group is a direct product of semisimple Lie groups $G = G_1 \times G_2$, then the Weyl group is also a direct product $W= W_1 \times W_2$. There could be other decompositions of $W$ unrelated to that though (see here for some example decompositions)
